# Mongo Aggregate by country and array of tags

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Im havving this problem with aggregate, i have categories with both tags and a country field, tags is an array of tags, and the country is a string.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54c8e2a72ec614e33c20595a"),
"__v" : 0,
"category_id" : 3,
"country" : "ar",
"name" : "Niños",
"tags" : [ 
    "juvenil",
    "nino",
    "ninos",
    "niño",
    "escolar",
    "escolares",
    "cartuchera",
    "unibike",
],
"parent" : ObjectId("54c8e2a72ec614e33c20594b"),
"updated_at" : ISODate("2016-06-06T15:13:26.659Z"),
"status" : true,
"slug" : "ropa-de-ninos",
"class" : "kids",
"order" : ""
}
```

and im doing an agregate of

```
db.getCollection('categories').aggregate([ 
{ '$match': 
    { tags: 
        { 
            '$in': [ 
                'ninos', 
                'escolar'
            ] 
        },
      country: 'ar' 
    }
},
{ '$project': 
    { 
        name: 1, 
        parent: 1, 
        country: 1, 
        tags: 1 
     } 
},
{ '$unwind': '$tags' },

{ 
    '$group': 
    { _id: '$_id', names: { '$push': '$tags' }, matches: { '$sum': 1 } } 
},
{ '$sort': { matches: -1 } } 
])
```

now if you look at the query i have both a tags $in and a country match, now with both on , i have no result, but if i take away the country it works perfectly.

what am I doing wrong?? i cant seem to se the problem, i have already tryed with separating the $match, puting the country first and then after the unwind the tags match.

Comment: yes, i know, that was a problem when i uploaded the code, in the DB it doesnt have any spaces. i will edit that

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What's your expected output, given the input sample document? I have run the above exact pipeline locally and it seems to "work" just fine, can you address the above?

Comment: well i have the same category for diferent countries, and sometimes the categories have the same tags, but diferent countries, what i want to achieve, is to do an agregate specifically on the categories of the country of the product. so the product will be categorize on that specific country

Comment: something like first select all the categories with the country 'ar' then agregate.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could use the [edit] link to append some sample documents for testing and the expected aggregation output with those sample documents since this is an IO type of problem which is best visualized with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).